# Vertical align not working for custom control

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to build a simple filter-bar which has a custom-control element.

The element should be aligned vertically but it seems not to be working. This is the markup for the filter-bar:

```
<div class="bg-light p-3 card">
    <form class="form-inline">
        <div class="form-row">
            <div class="col-auto">
                <input type="text" placeholder="The team's name" class="form-control" value="" />
            </div>
            <div class="col-auto">
                <select class="form-control">
                    <option value="">Select the season</option>
                    <option value="2019">2019</option>
                    <option value="2020">2020</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="col-auto">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-secondary">
                    <i class="fas fa-search"/>&nbsp;Search</button>
            </div>
            <div class="col-auto">
                <div class="custom-control custom-switch align-center">
                    <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="vpx" checked="" />
                    <label class="custom-control-label" for="vpx">Hide 0-point teams</label>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

But the result is shown below:

[image: Filter-bar]

No matter which `align-` class I add, the element won't move a bit. Already tried to set the `display` property to `inline-block` as stated in the bootstap-docs.
Only way to achieve something like centered is to add `mt-2` class but this seems not to be the correct way this should be done.

Comment: Can you share the CSS you used? and you want to vertical align the toggle button?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `align-items-center` to `form-row` and also close the `<i>` tag correctly on Search button

```css
body{ min-width: 800px;}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="bg-light p-3 card">
    <form class="form-inline">
        <div class="form-row align-items-center">
            <div class="col-auto">
                <input type="text" placeholder="The team's name" class="form-control" value="" />
            </div>
            <div class="col-auto">
                <select class="form-control">
                    <option value="">Select the season</option>
                    <option value="2019">2019</option>
                    <option value="2020">2020</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="col-auto">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-secondary">
                    <i class="fas fa-search">&nbsp;Search</i></button>
            </div>
            <div class="col-auto">
                <div class="custom-control custom-switch align-center">
                    <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="vpx" checked="" />
                    <label class="custom-control-label" for="vpx">Hide 0-point teams</label>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```